# Javascript Regex: Capture between two asterisks with multiple asterisks in comma delimited string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to capture all characters between multiple instances of asterisks, which are comma delimited in a string. Here's an example of the string:

```
checkboxID0*,*checkboxID1*,&checkboxID2&,*checkboxID3*,!checkboxID4!,checkboxID5*
```

The caveat is that the phrase must start and end with an asterisk. I have been able to come close by using the following regex, however, it won't discard any matches when the captured string is missing the ***starting*** asterisk(*):

```js
let str = "checkboxID0*,*checkboxID1*,&checkboxID2&,*checkboxID3*,!checkboxID4!,checkboxID5*"
const regex = /[^\,\*]+(?=\*)/gi;
var a = str.match(regex)
console.log(a) // answer should exclude checkboxID0 and checkboxID5
```

The answer returns the following, however, "**checkboxID0 and checkboxID5**" should be excluded as it doesn't start with an asterisk.

```
[
  "checkboxID0",
  "checkboxID1",
  "checkboxID3",
  "checkboxID5"
]
```

Thanks, in advance!

Comment: `checkboxID5` does not start with `*` either. I think you just need `/\*([^,*]+)\*/g`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vfhW5R/1) and [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/1bfw7934/).

Comment: Yes, I just noticed that I will edit it. The correct response should be "checkboxID1",
  "checkboxID3", Thanks for the prompt response and assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use asterisks on both ends of the pattern and capture all 1 or more chars other than commas and asterisks in between:

```
/\*([^,*]+)\*/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vfhW5R/1)

**Pattern details**

- `\*` - an asterisk
- `([^,*]+)` - Capturing group 1: one or more chars other than `,` and `*`
- `\*` - an asterisk

JS demo:

```js
var regex = /\*([^,*]+)\*/g;
var str = "checkboxID0*,*checkboxID1*,&checkboxID2&,*checkboxID3*,!checkboxID4!,checkboxID5*";
var m, res = [];
while (m = regex.exec(str)) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: So that returns all of the matching strings including the asterisks. I need the matching strings minus the asterisks - ie: checkboxID1, checkboxID3.

Comment: @azsl1326 No, that returns all of them **without** asterisks. You will see that if you run the JS code.

Comment: Okay, you are correct. I was looking at using the ReEx pattern to get the result via String.match(). If I use String.Match(), the asterisks are still there. Any way to alter the pattern so that I can return the desired result using String.Match() -as I was very close with my original pattern? Thanks!

Comment: @azsl1326 Only if you plan to support ECMAScript2018 (like Chrome): `str.match(/(?<=\*)[^,*]+(?=\*)/g)`. Everywhere else, you need to use capturing groups.